# Call to undefined method Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Collection\Interceptor::reset()

Tags: magento2

```
<?php

namespace custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Page;
use custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\CmsStaging\Model\PageApplier;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext;
use Magento\Staging\Model\StagingApplierInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;
/**
 * Class PageApplier
 */
class PluginPageApplier
{
    protected $_page;

    protected $emailHelper;

    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext
     */
    private $cacheContext;

    /**
     * PageStagingApplier constructor.
     * @param CacheContext $cacheContext
     */

    public function __construct(
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        CacheContext $cacheContext,
        page $page,
        Email $emailHelper,
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->cacheContext = $cacheContext;
        $this->_page = $page;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $entityIds
     * @return void
     */
    public function aroundExecute(PageApplier $subject, callable $proceed, array $entityIds)
    {
        if ($entityIds) 
        {
            $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(
                strtotime("now")
            );
        $select = $this->_page->getCollection()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->columns(['entity_id'])
                ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', ['id'])
                ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');
            $result = $this->_page
                ->getConnection()
                ->fetchOne($select);
            if (isset($result) && $result) {
                $this->emailHelper->sendEmail();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in attempting to invoke the "reset" function on the collection directly, rather than on the select. The collection does not possess a "reset" function. To resolve this, you should initially invoke "getSelect()" to obtain the select and subsequently call "reset" on it instead:

```
$select = $this->_page->getCollection()
                      ->getSelect()
                      ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                      ->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)
                      ->columns(['entity_id'])
                      ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', ['id'])
                      ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                      ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                      ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');
```